# Make CSS star rating dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The below code pen project consists of a pure css star rating interface.
https://codepen.io/yaworek/pen/JJpEaZ

Below is the css part:

```
/***
 *  Simple Pure CSS Star Rating Widget Bootstrap 4 
 * 
 *  www.TheMastercut.co
 *  
 ***/

@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

/* Styling h1 and links
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
h1[alt="Simple"] {color: white;}
a[href], a[href]:hover {color: grey; font-size: 0.5em; text-decoration: none}

.starrating > input {display: none;}  /* Remove radio buttons */

.starrating > label:before { 
  content: "\f005"; /* Star */
  margin: 2px;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block; 
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #000;
}

.starrating > label
{
  color: #FFFFFF; /* Start color when not clicked */
}

.starrating > input:checked ~ label
{ color: #ffca08 ; } /* Set yellow color when star checked */

.starrating > input:hover ~ label
{ color: #ffca08 ;  } /* Set yellow color when star hover */
```

It uses radio buttons and css to display the rating. I want to add additional rating sets on this. I want to add more rating sets like 5 rating sets for 5 books. Now the problem is, the css implementation resets the selected rating for one set while selecting rating for another set.

Below is the code pen link for an additional rating set that I have added. The problem is when I select rating for second set, the rating for first set is removed.
https://codepen.io/brainyprb/pen/BvoqLE

Is this solvable using css only ? or will I have to use javascript/jquery for this ?

Comment: have you tried with checkbox instead of radio buttons? else change the name="rating1", and the other as rating2. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PXPyar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use different name for each set of stars, as shown in img below 
Eg.

```
<input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating1" value="5" /><label for="star5" title="5 star">5</label>
        <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating1" value="4" /><label for="star4" title="4 star">4</label>
.................
<input type="radio" id="stare" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="stare" title="5 star">5</label>
        <input type="radio" id="stard" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="stard" title="4 star">4</label>
......................
```

[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frxcd.png)

Answer (score -1):

html side
if you put each div into a different   it works!